# Creating multiple Kotlin constructors that do not share common paramaters

Tags: kotlin, constructor

Lets say I have a simple data class that can be serialized to a string:

```
class Time(val hours: Int, val minutes: Int, val seconds: Int) {
    fun serialize(): String {
        return "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
}
```

How can I add a second constructor that allows me to construct this object using a serialized String? I expected to be able to use

```
constructor(serializedString: String) {
    val subs = serializedString.split(":")
    return Time(subs[0].toInt(),subs[1].toInt(),subs[2].toInt())
}
```

But come to find out that secondary constructors need to actually override the primary constructor. Obviously my secondary constructor in no way shape or form resembles my primary constructor.

- Is the correct answer here to simply make a `companion object` that contains a static `deserialize` method?
- Is there no way in Kotlin to make multiple constructors that accept different kinds of arguments?
- Or is the problem that I simply shouldn't have a primary constructor at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do not use primary constructor. Use two different secondary constructors:

```
class Time {

    val hours: Int
    val minutes: Int
    val seconds: Int

    constructor(hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) {
        this.hours = hours
        this.minutes = minutes
        this.seconds = seconds
    }

    constructor(serializedString: String) {
       val subs = serializedString.split(":")
       this.hours = subs[0].toInt()
       this.minutes = subs[1].toInt()
       this.seconds = subs[2].toInt()
    }

    fun serialize(): String{
        return "{%02d}:{%12d}:{%22d}".format(hours,minutes,seconds)
    }
}
```

In case if you need `data class` and `equals`/`hashCode` it will be better to use primary constructor with factory method in `companion object`.

Comment: Is there any kind of... "downside" to a class not having a primary constructor?

Comment: @JHixson Yes, `equals`/`hashCode` aren't generated. Also there are no `componentN` methods, so you can't use destructing declaration if you don't write it manually.

Comment: @Google I don't think this is correct, AFAIK `equals` and `hashCode` aren't generated automatically when you use a primary constructor. Are you thinking of [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)?

Comment: I can verify that I needed to add `data` to my class in order for it to generate `equals`.  That being said, I believe that a data class does need a primary constructor, as the primary constructor is what is utilized in the kotlin autogenerated `equals` method for data classes

Comment: Sorry guys, you are right about `equals` and `hashCode`. I've missed that `Time` isn't `data class`.

Answer (score 4):

Since `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` are properties of you class you can as well put them in a primary construtor and let the secondary call the primary one:

```
class Time(val hours: Int, val minutes: Int, val seconds: Int) {

    constructor(serializedString: String) : this(
        serializedString.split(":")[0].toInt(),
        serializedString.split(":")[1].toInt(),
        serializedString.split(":")[2].toInt()
    )

    fun serialize(): String {
        return "{%02d}:{%12d}:{%22d}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
}
```

Add the `data` keyword if you need it to be a `data class`.

Don't worry about `serializedString.split(":")` being called three times, it should not have any significant performance impact.